# How find word before ","?

Tags: c#, regex

So, my question:
I make this regex for find words, but i found problem on my regex.

```
Input: local lvlr,lvll = Audiosource:GetLevel()

@"(local.(?<vars>.*?)=)"

Output: lvlr,lvll
```

But I need them to be separated and were in the same group. It's possible ?

```
For example

Output: lvlr
Output: lvll
```

Comment: Please, define what is a good definition for you for a _word_.  If you have a regex to define what a word is for you, a good regex is `(<your_regex_for_a_word>),`, and use `$1` to get the word :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do with C# regex because each capturing group keeps track of each capture inside a group capture collection. However, your regex needs some adjustment for that feature to work.

It can look like

```
\blocal\s+(?:(?<vars>\w+),?\s*)+=
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cblocal%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Cvars%3E%5Cw%2B%29%2C%3F%5Cs*%29%2B%3D&i=local%20lvlr%2Clvll%20%3D%20Audiosource%3AGetLevel%28%29). A more efficient version of the regex is

```
\blocal\s+(?<vars>\w+)(?:,\s*(?<vars>\w+))*\s*=
```

[image]

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `local` - a substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:(?<vars>\w+),?\s*)+` - 1 or more occurrences of

  - `(?<vars>\w+)` - Group "vars": 1 or more word chars
  - `,?\s*` - an optional `,` followed with 0+ whitespaces
- `=` - a `=` symbol.

See an [example C# code](https://ideone.com/L2HzRG):

```
var s = "local lvlr,lvll = Audiosource:GetLevel()";
var pattern = @"\blocal\s+(?:(?<vars>\w+),?\s*)+=";
var result = Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
          .Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups["vars"].Captures)
          .ToList();
foreach (var coll in result)
    foreach (var v in coll)
        Console.WriteLine(v);
```

Output:

```
lvlr
lvll
```